# verify duration of audio file before uploading

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to check duration of audio file before uploading in similar way like file.size in the example below?

```
handleSubmit = async event =>
event.preventDefault();

if (this.file && this.file.size > config.MAX_ATTACHMENT_SIZE) {
  alert("Please pick a file smaller than" + config.MAX_ATTACHMENT_SIZE);
    return;
}
```

Comment: in case it is possible, it would likely be a functionality of the sound api you are using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550529/how-to-check-length-duration-of-an-uploaded-video-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we're talking about the browser, yes, it is. You can use `URL.createObjectURL()` on your `file`, use that as the `src` for an `<audio>` element you create, wait for the element's `canplaythrough` event, then read the `duration` property.

As a matter of fact, that code is available in my recent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797147/audio-object-duration-keeps-changing/51802281#51802281) (and reproduced below); it should be rather easy to integrate in your code.

```
function computeLength(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var mySound = new Audio([objectURL]);
    mySound.addEventListener(
      "canplaythrough",
      () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
        resolve({
          file,
          duration: mySound.duration
        });
      },
      false,
    );
  });  
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, how do you clean up (removeEventListener) the even listener though?

Comment: It shouldn't matter here, since `mySound` itself should only remain until `resolve` is called. Are you seeing memory leaks with this?

Comment: Not really, I've just always assumed non-removal of event listeners lead to memory leaks.